# Which theoretically drawn endings have high difference in material count?

Tags: endgame, draw, material-balance

Ending of King+Queen vs. King+Pawn is usually draw when pawn is on seventh rank of rook or bishop file, given that defending king is in front of it and attacking king is not close enough to force checkmate. In this case we have material difference of 8 points (9 for queen - 1 for pawn).

Similarly ending of King+Rook vs. King+Pawn is draw when attacking king and rook cannot both reach pawn before promotion, while defending king can - so we also have drawn ending with difference of 4 points (5 for rook - 1 for pawn).

What are other examples of drawn endings, disregarding fortresses, with such drastic differences in material count?

Edit: preferably legal and sensible positions.

Comment: King and 10 same coloured Bishops v. King

Comment: A stalemate with lots of queens on the board.

Comment: I think the main practical one is two knights against nothing. Fun side note, queen against two knights is often a draw. In that case blundering the queen does not change the evaluation.

Comment: About 5 points are needed at minimum to mate (in a pawnless ending) thus the R example is not *completely* surprising.